# Выделение опции при совпадении значения из текстового поля

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий набор опций:

```
<select id="currency">
    <option value="usd" selected>$</option>
    <option value="eur">€</option>
    <option value="yen">¥</option>
</select>
```

и `input` со значением:

```
<input type="text" value="eur">
```

Как проще всего реализовать выделение селектора по совпадению значения из текстового поля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пояснения в комментариях

```js
// Взять значение из `input`
var value = $('input[type=text]').val();

// Получить все значения из `select` (один из многих способов)
var values = $.map( $('#currency option'), function(option) { return option.value });

// Проверить содержится ли значение из `input` в `select`
if ( values.indexOf(value) !== -1 ) {

  // Установить значение `select`
  $('#currency').val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="currency">
    <option value="usd" selected>$</option>
    <option value="eur">€</option>
    <option value="yen">¥</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="eur">
```

Comment: Спасибо, это почти то, что нужно. А можно добавить проверку совпадения со значениями селекта? То есть, если в текстовом поле будет не "eur", a "euro", то опция будет пустой. Чтоб не было подобных ситуаций.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev а сейчас разве не так? Попробуйте вводить значения в `input`. Введите `eur`, а затем `euro`. В первом случае в `select` отобразится `€`, во втором ничего.

Comment: Так наоборот хотелось избежать этого. Если значение input не совпадает с select, то игнорировать замену опции.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev изменил код в соответствии с уточнением задачи

Comment: По прежнему, если у input задать euro, опции select становятся пустыми. Вот [пример](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrjdxM).

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev исправил

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Надо перехватить событие для `select` `chage` и если его значение ровно значению текстового поля то дать ему какой то класс, иначе убрать класс.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#currency').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == $('#cur_input').val()){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#currency.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="currency">
    <option value="usd" selected>$</option>
    <option value="eur">€</option>
    <option value="yen">¥</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="eur" id="cur_input">
```

Вот второй вариант, здесь когда текст `input` совпадает с одним из значений `select` этот оно выбирается и они высвечиваются. Еще опции проверяются после загрузки страницы. Так универсально.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="currency">
    <option value="" selected>select currency</option>
    <option value="usd">$</option>
    <option value="eur">€</option>
    <option value="yen">¥</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="eur" id="cur_input">
<style>
    .active{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function if_isset_opt($this){
        var opts = $('#currency>option');
        for(var i=0;i< opts.length;i++){
            $('#currency').removeClass('active');
            $this.removeClass('active');
            $('#currency>option').removeAttr('selected');
            if($(opts[i]).val() == $this.val() && $this.val() != ''){        
                $('#currency').addClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
                $(opts[i]).attr('selected','selected');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if_isset_opt($('#cur_input'));
    
    $('#cur_input').on('keyup',function(){
        if_isset_opt($(this));        
    });
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Мне событие с изменением не подойдет. Необходимо, чтоб значение селектора изменилось, если значение поля совпало с ним, при открытии страницы. То есть, чтоб была открыта опция с евро.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev давай так скажи что должно измениться и после чего , дай пример с элементами конкретными например в ответе

Comment: Разметка аналогичная примеру в ответе. Только `select` и `input`. Необходимо взять значение из `input`, в нашем случае это eur. И если одно из значений опций в `select` совпадает со значением из `input`, оно должно стать активным. То есть, при открытии документа, скрипт должен выбрать селектор с иконкой евро.